# Meteor not returning data for single document

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
Router.route('/tickets/:sku',
    {
        name:'selectedTicket',
        template:'selectedTicket',
        waitOn:function() {

            return Meteor.subscribe('selectedTickets',this.params.sku);
        },
        data:function()
        {
            return  Ticket.find({sku:this.params.sku});
        }
    })
```

This is the code pertaining to this particular page from my router page

```
<template name="selectedTicket">

    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 60px">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m6">
                <img src="/images/data/{{image}}" class="responsive-img" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12 m6">
                <h1>{{name}}</h1><p class="lead"><i>{{Host}}</i></p>
                <p class="lead">{{location}}</p>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12 m6">
                        <h3>{{money price}}</h3>
                        <hr/>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="add-to-cart">
                                <i class="mdi mdi-cart"></i>
                                Add To Cart
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

This is the code for my template.

The problem i am having is that when i select a particular item, it goes to the page meant to show the information for that item, but the page comes up blank.
[image: image for single item]
[image: image showing all data]

Comment: yes, it is rendering the DOM elements....no errors present in the browser log

Comment: Can you try in your data function: 

console.log(Ticket.find({sku:this.params.sku}).count())

If it returns zero you need to modify your mongo selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using `{{#each}}` or `{{#with}}` you need your route to directly return the data and not a cursor. Therefore use `.findOne()` instead of `.find()`

```
data:function(){
  return  Ticket.findOne({sku:this.params.sku});
}
```

Comment: I know i'm meant to use findOne() but when i use it meteor gives me the error..."Error: Publish function can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors"..

Comment: Not in your publish function on the server, in your *route*!